# I think this is bad C++ coding ('new' in a function to point to a local variable). Am I correct?

Tags: c++, object, memory

I want to create a class that contains a pointer, and upon initialization, the pointer can be dereferenced to give an integer assigned at initialisation.

This was my first attempt to write this code. This passed compiler and gave me the correct result without warning. However I later think this code has a potential problem.

That is in the constructor, the integer a is created on a stack framed to the constructor function. I am however making 'ptr' pointing to this stack memory address. The problem is this memory can be reused upon maybe calling other functions, so I might get garbage value if I am not lucky.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class P {
  public:
    int *ptr;
    P(int);
};

P::P(int a){
  int *ptr = new int (0);
  ptr = &a;
}

int main() {
  P p(99);

  cout <<*(p.ptr) <<endl;

}
```

A better way would be to create an integer variable on heap, copy the value of a to that variable, and make ptr pointing to that memory space on heap.

```
P::P(int a){
  int *i = new int (0);
  *i = a;
  ptr = i;
}
```

Is my analysis correct?

Thanks!

Comment: When you have undefined behaviour, you're *un*lucky if a program works or you get garbage values, since your program is broken. The second would work but is quite a bit more complicated than `ptr = new int(a);`.

Comment: Are you sure your code does what you want? You create a new local pointer with int* ptr which hides the class member in your constructor. You should use ptr = new int(0); *ptr = a, not ptr = &a. Or even shorter ptr = new int(a)

Comment: indeed, ptr = new int (a) was what I was looking for... thx for pointing out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statements

```
int *ptr = new int (0);
ptr = &a;
```

are problematic, but probably not because of the reasons you think.

The reason it's problematic is because you define a *new* and distinct local variable `ptr` inside the function. This is *not* the same as the `P::ptr` member variable.

There's also a second problem, which is a *memory leak*. You allocate memory with `new`, but you never free the memory with `delete`.

---

If you really is required to use a raw and non-owning pointer to a single `int` value, I recommend you do it using a constructor initializer list:

```
P(int a)
  : ptr{ new int(a) }
{
  // Empty
}
```

Here `new int(a)` will create a new `int` value and copy the value of `a` into it.

Remember to then create a destructor which free's the memory you have allocated. And then you need to learn about [the rules of three, five and zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

To use the rule of zero, and to avoid memory leaks and make life simpler, use a *smart pointer* like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
struct P
{
  std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;

  P(int a)
    : ptr{ std::make_unique<int>(a) }
  {
  }
};
```

And of course, since it's just about a single `int` value, and you don't need a reference to the original value, there's no need for pointers at all.

Comment: *but you never free the memory with `delete`.* and thanks to `ptr = &a;` it's next to impossible to find the `int` to delete it if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. I have not  got to smart pointer but will be sure to keep an eye on it as I continue my learning...

Comment: @Learning_man IMO, any teacher, class, tutorial or book that teaches the use of raw pointers before the standard library is doing you a disservice.

Comment: I can very much relate to that... although the class material does emphasize "here you see the use of new and delete, but in C++ you won't have to use it as much, we will soon see why". I am well aware of this fact but nevertheless I'm glad I wrote so many bad codes and learning why they are bad in this early stage..

Comment: `make_unique<int>` makes no sense here because if the pointer isn't shared you might as well just have `int`. And if it is shared then you need a `shared_ptr`. Same goes for a raw pointer.